# Have CentOS push custom updates to windows 7 clients

Tags: centos, windows

Is there anyway do deploy updates for Windows OS desktops, from a custom source? I frequently work on computers, and installing Windows 7 with an OEM disk and waiting for my slow internet connection to pull the updates, is unbearable. I don't know what is my best recourse.

More or less, I want to push updates to Windows Vista/7/8 using a Linux based server.  Is there anyway this is possible?

Comment: To ask the obvious question - is the native Windows Server Update Service not appropriate for some reason? Why a preferred Linux one?

Comment: These would be client computers, so I don't want them on a domain. Also, I am trying to speed things up and keeping this all in house. I used the [windowsupdatesdownloader tool](http://www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com/) to download the updates for various versions of windows, and they're on my CentOS server.

Comment: Presumably, you'd have the Linux box serve the patches out with HTTP (either directly or via a proxy-cache), CIFS, etc. I think your real question is how to get the Windows machines(s) to go to your server for the upgrades. For that, you're probably better off on [su] or [sf].

Comment: It's funny you mention that because that's the conclusion I made this morning.

Comment: @AustinKregel It's funny that you had to be rude about it.

Comment: I wasn't being rude. Please don't assume there is a tone to what I wrote.